# Convert an object to a query string

Tags: javascript

i have the following object

```
let filters = {
  first_ids: [1,2,3],
  second_ids: [2,4,9]
}
```

Now, i want to loop over them and then return something like the following.

```
filters[first_ids][]=1&filters[first_ids][]=2&filters[first_ids][]=3&filters[second_ids][]=2&filters[second_ids][]=4&filters[second_ids][]=9&
```

What i tried is following, but i know this is not a elegant way.

```
 let filters = {
  first_ids: [1,2,3],
  second_ids: [2,4,9]
}


let finalFilters = []
let firstFilters = filters.first_ids.map((e) => `filters[first_ids][]=${e}&`)
let secondFilters = filters.second_ids.map((e) => `filters[second_ids][]=${e}&`)
finalFilters.push(firstFilters)
finalFilters.push(secondFilters)
finalFilters.toString().replace(/,/g, "")
```

Also the filters object can have more keys.

Comment: Are you looking for [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)?

Comment: do you want a string as result?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```js
let filters = {
  first_ids: [1, 2, 3],
  second_ids: [2, 4, 9],
};

const output = Object.entries(filters).flatMap(([name, ids]) => {
  return ids.map(id => {
    return `filters[${encodeURIComponent(name)}]=${encodeURIComponent(id)}`;
  });
}).join('&');

console.log(output)
```

The main idea is to look though each key, value pair in the object `fitlers`, then loop though all the ids, and construct the query string fragment, and finally join it on `&`.

Take a look at [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a nested approach for generating the string.

```js
const
    filters = { first_ids: [1, 2, 3], second_ids: [2, 4, 9] },
    result = Object
        .entries(filters)
        .flatMap(([k, a]) => a.map(v => `filters[${k}][]=${v}`))
        .join('&');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` into an array first and then use `join`.

```js
let filters = {
  first_ids: [1, 2, 3],
  second_ids: [2, 4, 9],
};

const res = Object.entries(filters)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => (v.forEach((n) => r.push(`filters[${k}][]=${n}`)), r), [])
  .join("&");

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some generic solution:

```js
function toPhpQueryString(o, key) {
    if (o === null || o === undefined)
        return '';

    if (typeof o !== 'object')
        return key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(o);

    if (Array.isArray(o))
        return o.map(v =>
            toPhpQueryString(v, key + '[]')).join('&');

    return Object.entries(o).map(p =>
        toPhpQueryString(p[1], key + '[' + p[0] + ']')).join('&');
}

//

let filters = {
    first_ids: [1, 2, 3],
    second_ids: [2, 4, 9],
    deep: {
        object: {
            abc: [33, 44],
            xyz: 'hey',
        }
    }
}

qs = toPhpQueryString(filters, 'filters');
console.log(qs)
```